# If $X_i \backsim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, $i = 1,2,...,n$, then are $X_1 + X_2$ and $ X_1 - X_2$ independent and normally distributed?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, independence

Studying Bain's book on introduction to statistics I saw that if $X_i \backsim N(\mu_i, \sigma_{i}^2)$ $i =1,2,...,n$ denote independent normal variables, then $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_{i}X_{i}} \backsim N(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_{i}{\mu}}, \sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_{i}^{2}\sigma_{i}^{2}})$, furthermore, I learned that $\overline{X}$ and the terms $X_i - \overline{X}$ are independent. Likewise, $\overline{X}$ and $S^2$ are independent. But the doubt remains in me that if $X_1 + X_2$  and $X_1 - X_2$ are independent, that is, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent normal random variables, $X_i \backsim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, and if $Y_1 = X_1 + X_2$ and $Y_2 = X_1 - X_2$, then are $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ independent and normally distributed?

I don't have enough ideas to answer this, and I appreciate any good help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_i\sim\operatorname N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$ are independent then $\sum_i a_i X_i$ and $\sum_i b_i X_i$ (where $a_i,b_i$ are constant, i.e. not random) are independent if their covariance is $0.$
\begin{align}
& \operatorname{cov}(X_1+X_2, X_1-X_2) \\[8pt]
= {} & \operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_1) + \operatorname{cov}(X_2,X_1) - \operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_2) - \operatorname{cov}(X_2,X_2) \\[8pt]
= {} & \sigma_1^2 + 0 - 0 - \sigma_2^2.
\end{align}
So $X_1+X_2,X_1-X_2$ are independent if, and only if, $\sigma_1^2= \sigma_2^2.$

Comment: Now I understand very good. Thanks so much.